# json: unsupported type: func()

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Besides functions in Go, are there any other types that cannot be marshaled using json.Marhsal?

If I pass a func to json.Marshal, I get:

```
json: unsupported type: func()
```

are there any other data types in Golang that can't be serialized / marshaled? I am writing a mini-library and want to know if I need to check for other things which can't be serialized.

Comment: You should ask the opposite: what objects supports marshaling? I believe Go docs covers this, have a look there.

Comment: Just read the package doc it explains in detail what can and cannot be marshaled.

Answer (score 2):

From [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Channel, complex, and function values cannot be encoded in JSON. Attempting to encode such a value causes Marshal to return an UnsupportedTypeError.
>
> JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures and Marshal does not handle them. Passing cyclic structures to Marshal will result in an infinite recursion.

Going further, not mentioned in the doc, but `unsafe.Pointer` also cannot be marshaled.

Same goes for any composite type containing an unsupported type (e.g. slice of channels, struct holding an `unsafe.Pointer` exported field etc.).

Comment: Is there any way to specify a custom marshalling function, or to replace them by "null" ?

Comment: @AntoineViallon Of course. You can implement `json.Marshaler` on your type, and in that, you do whatever you want to.